# Slurm - job name, job ids, how to know which job is which?

Tags: slurm

I often run many jobs on slurm. Some finish faster than others. However, it is always hard to keep track which job is which. Can I give custom job names on slurm? If so what is the command on the batch script? Would that show up when I do `squeue --me`?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter is `--job-name` (or `-J`), for instance:

```
#SBATCH --job-name=exp1_run2
```

The `squeue` output will list `exp1_run2` for the corresponding job ID under column `NAME`.

Comment: Do you know if is possible to cancel a job using job name instead of job id?